# How to add an image title in XSL?

Tags: image, xslt, attributes

I would like to add a title below each image. My xsl-file looks like this where I loop through each image:

```
    <Testresult>
      <xsl:for-each select="Testresult/image">        
        <img src="{@href}" width="333px" length="350px"/>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="//Type"/></title>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="Testresult/Image"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>       
    </Testresult>
```

My xml-file looks like this:

```
    <Testresult>
    <image href="c:\image1.png"/>
    <image href="c:\image2.png"/>
    </Testresult>
```

The output should look like this:

[image]

thanks for the help!

Comment: you can add `<title><xsl:value-of select="{//Type}"/></title>` after the `img` tag

Comment: @Joel You mean like this?! 
'**<img src="{@href}" title="{//Typ}" width="333px" length="350px"/>
   <title><xsl:value-of select="{//Type}"/></title>**'

This does not work unfortunately

Comment: To be more precise; I would like to add below the image the path of each image!

Comment: Can you show an output example? With Input, of course..

Comment: Try the suggestion by @JoelM.Lamsen again, only this time remove the `{ }`. Like this: `<title><xsl:value-of select="//Type"/></title>`. You probably don't want to use `//Type` either, but it's impossible to tell with no sample input.

Comment: I forgot to delete those braces. Please provide your complete input XML, your expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen it does not work so far. I updated my question with an example. Would appreciate if someone knows how to do it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Testresult>
            <xsl:for-each select="Testresult/image">        
                <img src="{@href}" width="333px" length="350px"/>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></title>
            </xsl:for-each>       
        </Testresult>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried it but the titles are not shown unfortunately!